# Initializing an array within a c++ constructor

Tags: c++

I want to have an array as a class member, but the only way I know how to initialize the array in the constructor is by adding each element individually (array[x] = char)

```
class MyClass
{
  public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();
    void PrintLetters(); // Prints each character in the array
  private:
    int alpha[3]; // Allocate memory for array
};

MyClass::MyClass()
{
    // Initialize the array
    alpha[0] = 1;
    alpha[1] = 2;
    alpha[2] = 3;

    PrintLetters();
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
}

void MyClass::PrintLetters()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x += 1)
    {
        cout << alpha[x] << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    MyClass abc;

    return 0;
}
```

Is there another way to do it? If I try to do it like this:

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
    // Initialize the array
    alpha[3] = {1, 2, 3};

    PrintLetters();
}
```

I get the following error: Expression syntax in turbo c++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe in GCC at least, with `-std=c++11`, you can do this:

```
MyClass::MyClass() : alpha{1, 2, 3}
{
    PrintLetters();
}
```

This is just an array initialization in the member initialization list. It's a standard C++ feature, but some compilers (*cough* VC++ *cough*) might not have implemented it yet.

Comment: I confirm it still doesn't work with VC2013...

Comment: The [web compiler](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) compiles it. So yes, it has been implemented.

Comment: Works `std::array` in VC120, IIRC.

Comment: `int alpha[3] = {1, 2, 3};` inside the class definition would also work, assuming c++11 support.

Comment: @Michael I'm relatively sure that *that*'s wasn't implemented in in VC140 last time I checked.